# loading firebase data on page loaded in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I searched for long time, I only can find a solution using addListenerForSingle Event which is triggered onDataChanged.   It only triggered when there was a change on database....

How can I get a single value with page loaded (I mean onCreate)?

For example, get key is really easy,

```
mReference.child("kotran").child("isactive").getKey()
//isactive
```

But there no way to get value.

Comment: To get a value from Firebase you attach a listener. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: I know I can get a value from listener, but It only has method like onDataChange... when page is loaded, onDatachange is not called.I want to get value when oncreate is called.

Comment: The `onDataChange` immediately fires with the current value. From the docs: "This method is triggered once **when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes." The listener fires straight away (try it, it does). If you're having problems making this work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Pd.Jung Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will be called once, the first time you register such listener.
Take a look at this generic Kotlin example for the whole function:

```
override fun <T : Any> getValue(typeClass: KClass<T>, reference: String, vararg children: String): Single<T> =
        Single.create({
            val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(reference)

            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(dbError: DatabaseError?) {
                    it.onError(FirebaseDatabaseException(
                            dbError?.message ?: context stringOf R.string.database_error,
                            dbError?.details ?: exceptionDetails(reference, children))
                    )
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                    val value = childDataSnapshot(dataSnapshot, children)?.getValue(typeClass.java)
                    if (value != null) {
                        it.onSuccess(value)
                    } else {
                        it.onError(RetreivedValueNullException(exceptionDetails(reference, children)))
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```

It is returning `Single<T>`, however, if you're not using `RxJava`, just remove related `Single.create` wrap and return `T`

Implementation of `exceptionDetails()`:

```
private fun exceptionDetails(reference: String, children: Array<out String>): String =
        "Exception occurred on reference: $reference and children: ${children.forEach { String.format("-> %s", it) }}"
```

And usage example (if this function is in some `FirebaseRepository`:

```
firebaseRepository.getValue(Boolean::class, "kotran", "isActive")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ /* do something with the value */}, 
               { /* do something with the error */})
```

More detailes available on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bajicdusko/95300d68b4b742f3dbfbc6f23440b84c).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getValue()` method in Firebase that works directly on a reference, like getKey(). To get a value you need to use a listener. The `onDataChange()` method immediately returns the current value. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) is the official docs from Firebase. Please check the `listen for value events` section.

Hope it helps.